# Python RSA encryption errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, rsa

I'm trying to create a simple version of RSA in Python, but - whether it is due to the limitations of Python integers or my awful code - it is not returning the same decrypted message as the original. My key generator does seem to create valid keys, so I am curious as to how it is failing.

Attached is the code I used - I thought it was short enough to not need to add a stub.

```
from random import randint
from math import sqrt, ceil

#This is the private key the bank uses
bankPrime = 6619319052850372576671203008980947142174030778088896832879139788043990604607
#This is the public key
clientPrime = 89981040860183284202926925086489690550566335265876097787978356913003610730551
#Calculate modulus
modulus = bankPrime * clientPrime

#Calculate totient of modulus
totient = (bankPrime - 1)*(clientPrime - 1)

#Creates random numbers until it passes Euclid's algorithm with the GCD being 1 - coprime generator
def xgcd(b, n):
    x0, x1, y0, y1 = 1, 0, 0, 1
    while n != 0:
        q, b, n = b // n, n, b % n
        x0, x1 = x1, x0 - q * x1
        y0, y1 = y1, y0 - q * y1
    return b, x0

while True:
    pubkeyexponent = randint(3, ceil(sqrt(totient)))
    gcd, prikeyexponent = xgcd(pubkeyexponent, totient)
    if prikeyexponent < 0:
        prikeyexponent += totient
    if gcd == 1:
        break

print("Totient n", totient)
print("Private Key d", prikeyexponent)
print("Public Key e", pubkeyexponent)
print("Modulus", modulus)
print()
print("Type the message you want to encrypt:")
message = input(">:")

encrypted = 0
for x in range(len(message)):
    encrypted += (256**x) * ord(message[x])
print(encrypted)

networkmessage = pow(encrypted, pubkeyexponent, totient)
print("The number message sent over the network to the bank is this:", networkmessage)
encrypted = pow(networkmessage, prikeyexponent, totient)
print("The number message sent back to the client is this:", encrypted)
```

Comment: `pow(encrypted, pubkeyexponent, totient)` and `pow(networkmessage, prikeyexponent, totient)` are using the wrong modulus. Replace `totient` with `modulus` in these lines.

Comment: Better late than never - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use [cryptographer](https://pypi.org/cryptographer)

This code will encrypt, decrypt, save RSA keys to a file, and load them back again.

```
from cryptographer import RSAKey()
key = RSAKey()
encrypted = key.encrypt('Hello World') # also works with bytes data
print('Encrypted Text:', encrypted)
decrypted = key.decrypt(encrypted)
print('Decrypted Text:', decrypted)
# Save key to file
import pickle
pickle.dump(rsa, open('rsa.dat', 'wb')
# Load key from file
old_rsa = rsa
rsa = pickle.load(open('rsa.dat', 'rb'))
print(rsa == old_rsa) # True
```